# Проблема с задачей на Pascal

Tags: pascal

возникла проблема с решением задачи.
Суть задачи: генерируются рандомные символ на русского алфавита, и среди этих символов находится вводимое пользователем слово, причём кол-во символов в слове так же задаётся. Сами символы выводятся на экран.
Проверка осуществляется так: допустим это наша последовательность: abcdefghi, тогда при слове из 4 символов мы должны будем проверять на "а не наше ли это слово? вот эти последовательности: abcd bcde cdef defg и т.д. Ограничение в задаче: нельзя использовать функции, массивы и т.д, только условия, циклы и функцию random.
Вот мой код:

```
const k = 4;
var 
  s, s1, s2: string;
  c: char;
  i: byte;
begin
  readln(s2);
  s := '';
  s1 := '';
  while s <> s2 do
  begin
    for i := 1 to k do
    begin
      c := char(random(ord('я') - ord('а') + 1) + ord('а'));
      write(c);
      s := s + c;
      if i = 2 then
        s1 := s1 + c;
      if s = s2 then
        break
      else 
        s := s1;
    end;
    s1 := '';
  end;
  writeln;
  writeln(s);
end.
```

Проблема в том, что программа очень долго ищет слово, и не находит, следовательно что-то не так4 с условием поиска. Помогите найти ошибку

Comment: Зачем столько `begin` операторов? И да, в чем собственно вопрос?

Comment: предлагаю записать код в одну строку, будет еще удобнее читать. зы: вы проблему своего кода то опишите, или мы догадаться должны?

Comment: проблема в том, что слово эта программа ищет очень долго, и не находит, следовательно, что-то не так с условием поиска, а что именно я понять не могу

Comment: На условии `if i = 2 then` мой мозг отключился.

Answer (score 1):

Если переменные назвать осмысленно, легче будет читать и разбираться.

А логика может быть такой:

полностью сформировать случайную строку

пройти в цикле по начальном индексу от 1 до разницы длин случайной и искомой строк

пройти во внутреннем цикле по длине искомой строки, сравнивая символы

получается, что искомая строка как бы прикладывается к случайной с начала, потом сдвигается на 1, потом на 2 и т.д.

Comment: "Задание: Напишите Ваш собственный вариант функции `Pos`."

Comment: @Igor Ну да, я так понял, что требуется самый примитивный вариант